# Gauge fixing the Einstein's gravity action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, black-holes, entropy

This is in reference to [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4061) paper, arXiv:1204.4061.

1. I was wondering if someone can give me a reference which explains this gravitational gauge fixing that they have done in $2.10$ and how that leads to $2.11$ - I have never seen this.
2. Can't this whole technology be carried through if you just had R and no $F^2$ in the Lagrangian? (..and instead of these black holes may be have AdS written as a topological black-hole...)
3. The calculation that happens till equation $2.17$ is also quite opaque to me. Any help will be great.

Comment: For (1), the gauge $F(h) = (D^\mu h_{\mu \rho} - \frac{1}{2} D_\rho h^\mu_\mu)=0$ is the harmonic gauge. So, in a Fadeev-Popov-like process, it would be logic to find a $F^2$ term in the Lagrangian, as the gauge-gixing part of the Lagrangian (we have to add also the Fadeev-Popop-like ghost Lagrangian term)

Comment: @Trimok You have any reference from where one can learn about gauge fixing the Einstein-Hilbert action in this harmonic gauge? I didn't understand what you said about the F^2 term - that is the usual Fadeev popov that is happening here completely independent of the gravity sector - right? I guess the gauge fixings of the two things are not talking to each other in any way! right?

Comment: No, sorry, I have not a precise reference. My observation was about the analogy with usual Fadeev Popov process. When you have a gauge constraint $F=0$, you get a $F^2$ term (+ ghosts) in the total lagrangian. So I supposed that this would  be a "gravitational" Fadeev-Popop-like mechanism. The paper speaks (below $2.13$), about "diﬀeomorphism ghosts". At the gauge fixing level, The electromagnetic part seems to be independent - a gauge $G(A) = \partial^\mu A_\mu=0$ giving a $G^2$ term in the Lagrangian (+ Maxwell ghosts).